# Libgdx Stencil & ShapeRenderer

Tags: android, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkdSO.jpg)

The whole screen will be black, then the insides of the triangle shape are the parts that will only appear.

I tried using SCISSOR but it is rectangle in shape.

*Original Image Source: https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/screenshots/casestudies/onslaught/controls_tutorial.png

Comment: You have a lot of ways to make the effect you are trying to reach. The easiest way that come to my mind is using the Stencil Buffer (there are plenty of tutorials related to the stencil test).
If you want a more general answer, this wiki as a section for masking: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Masking

Comment: It only indicates scissor, which is rectangle in shape.

Comment: I know it is not OpenGL ES, but this should be very close:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Stencil_buffer

In the example, the stencil is used with a circle, but drawing a triangle should be easier.

Comment: I'll get to it. Thanks :)

Comment: If you succeed to write something, do not hesitate to paste it if something fail, I'll try to take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you can render a masked image. One possible way is to use the depth buffer. I've written a small method that shows the process of setting up the buffer using a ShapeRenderer to define a triangular region of the image to render and mask out the remainder. The triangle mask could be replaced by any other shape that the ShapeRenderer is capable of rendering.

```
// For a 2D image use an OrthographicCamera
OrthographicCamera cam = new OrthographicCamera();
ShapeRenderer shapes = new ShapeRenderer();
cam.setToOrtho(true, screenWidth, screenHeight);
shapes.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

private void renderStencilImage(float runTime){
    // Clear the buffer
    Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Disable writing to frame buffer and
    // Set up the depth test
    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);
    Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LESS);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
    //Here add your mask shape rendering code i.e. rectangle
    //triangle, or other polygonal shape mask
    shapes.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapes.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f);
    shapes.triangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
    shapes.end();
    // Enable writing to the FrameBuffer
    // and set up the texture to render with the mask
    // applied
    Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
    Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
    Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_EQUAL);
    // Here add your texture rendering code
    batcher.begin();
    renderFrame(runTime);
    batcher.end();
    // Ensure depth test is disabled so that depth
    // testing is not run on other rendering code.
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Before you call the method, you must first create a ShapeRenderer and set the projection matrix. You must also set the depth buffer option in the android config in the onCreate method like this:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.depth = 15;
    initialize(new game(), config);
}
```

The options for glDepthFunc define how the mask is applied to the texture. Check out the [OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Test) to see the arguments that can be passed to the function.

Comment: Works perfectly on desktop too!